# A possible absolute reference system

Tags: special-relativity

What about considering the microwave background radiation (2.7K if I remember well) as a reference system with some absolute character? Please explains if this question make sense and possible answers.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is a frame prominently used in cosmology. Still, one may neglect the weak CMB (or shield a system from it) to see that all other frames in relative motion with respect to the CMB frame still follow the same laws of physics.

Answer (score 1):

No more absolute than using the position of distant Quasars